# NoSQL (Cassandra, MongoDB..) views and changing masterdata

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, data-modeling, nosql

I'm currently try to design a "table" model in Cassandra (but the questions belongs also to other NoSql databases like MongoDB).

Following scenario:

- Very much gps positions from vehicles to store
- a vehicle belongs to one company
- a vehicle could belong to one or many vehicle groups (in a company)
- a user belongs to one company
- a user could have the right for one or many vehicle groups (in his company)

I try to design the "tables" like the users query for the data, for example:
gpsposition_by_company:
company | vehiclegroup | vehicle | longitude | latitude

Now my problem:
What should i do, if a vehicle or a user changes his group membership?

Currently I see a few options:

1. don't save the vehicle group in the materialized views, instead use a relationship "table". So I have to query first, for the allowed vehicles of a user and second query for each vehicles gpspositions
2. also use a relationship table, but query for all gps positions of a company a filter the allowed vehicles on the server side.

Both options doesn't look fine for me. What do you think about it? Are there any patterns to solve this problems in non-relational databases?

Regards 
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your problem depends on your level of comfort with polyglot persistence. Working on similar use case we did a hybrid of having all relational data in relational database and metrics (in your case gps locations) saved in Cassandra as time series. This gave us flexibility of updating relational data (move vehicle from one group to another, update its parameters etc) but also the possibility to save and later analyze data (vehicle movement, time it took from A to B etc).
You can go with Cassandra only but it will take you a lot of time and you will have to navigate around a lot of problems.

Comment: We also see the possibility to manage the relational master data in a relational db, instead of cassandra. But how to retrieve effective the gps positions from cassandra without joins? So we could only retrieve the data for each vehicle separately and merge it on the server!?

Comment: Yes you will need to have application level joins.